# woocommerce add price to cart button with ajax class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After researching this issue I found code that will add the price to the "Add to cart" button like this:

[ $50 Add to cart ]

The code for some reason does not use the ajax class so when the button is clicked the page reloads. The normal default button will use an ajax class so when it's clicked it does not reload the page but will show a message that it's been added to the cart.

I am overriding the file add-to-cart.php by adding it to my theme at \woocommerce\loop\add-to-cart.php

Here's the code that does not use ajax class:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">%s %s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        $product->get_price_html(),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

How can I modify this to use the ajax class of the default add to cart button?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the add to cart template is a very dangerous template to override. You didn't say which version of WooCommerce you are using, but I am going to assume 2.5? I assume that because I helped rewrite the WooCommerce ajax add to cart code to trigger on the `.ajax_add_to_cart` class because it resolved a complex issue I was having with the Name Your Price and Subscriptions extensions. But since you are overriding the template you aren't getting the 2.5 updates.

Here's the new [`add-to-cart.php` template](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php) and the updated [`woocommerce_template_add_to_cart()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/47a74f96cd7bdb92da50001f02666c1bf415f4d0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L612-L630) function.

You can see the classes being passed to the template in the first and defined in the second via an `implode()` on an array. So to import that piece of code into yours you would get:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">%s %s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
                        'button',
                        'product_type_' . $product->product_type,
                        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                        $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : ''
                ) ) ),
        esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
        $product->get_price_html(),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

Though, I'd strongly advise you not override this template. From your code, I don't see any modification that makes it different/custom, which basically means you open yourself up to issues with upgrading and for no benefit.

Comment: Thank you for answering. How would you recommend adding the price to the [Add to cart] button in a safe way to allow for updates?

Comment: That's a different question, but you would need to filter the value of `$product->add_to_cart_text()`.... which can be done via  `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text`.

Comment: `.ajax_add_to_cart` did the trick for me. But I still ignore what mechanism bind ajax to links, any hints ?

Comment: Adding the `.ajax_add_to_cart` class and I think also `data-product_id=99` to the add to cart button are enough to get ajax working on the single product page these. Though you will run into compatibility issues with plugins that add fields/inputs to the add to cart form. The best versions of this actually serialize and relay ALL form inputs via ajax for broadest compatibility. Not sure what you mean by "ignore what mechanism bind ajax" so can't advise on that.

Answer (score 0):

Button already has `ajax_add_to_cart` class which bind the Ajax call.
Just make sure you have enabled Ajax add to cart button

Go to `Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Display` and check `Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives`

Also it is only works when you are adding products from product archive page, it will not work from product single page.

Reference: [Configuring Woocommerce Settings](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/#section-2)

Comment: I have "AJAX add to cart buttons on archives" enabled and it works fine when I'm using the default add-to-cart.php but when I use the modified version that adds the price to the button AJAX no longer works on it. There's not much difference in the original and modified version of the file. I just don't understand where it's losing the AJAX call.